# Nodejs example for pachyderm

Tags: node.js, pachyderm

I am new to Pachyderm.

I have a pipeline to extract, transform and then save in the db.
Everything is already written in nodejs, docekrized.
Now, I would like to move and use pachyderm.

I tried following the python examples they provided, but creating this new pipeline always fails and the job never starts.

All my code does is take the `/pfs/data` and copy it to `/pfs/out`.

Here is my pipeline definition

```
{
    "pipeline": {
        "name": "copy"
    },
    "transform": {
        "cmd": ["npm", "start"],
        "image": "simple-node-docker"
    },
    "input": {
        "pfs": {
            "repo": "data",
            "glob": "/*"
        }
    }
}
```

All that happens is that the pipeline fails and the job never starts.

Is there a way to debug on why the pipeline is failing?
Is there something special about my docker image that needs to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Offhand I see two possible issues:

1. The image name doesn't have a prefix. By default, images are pulled from dockerhub, and dockerhub images are prefixed with the user who owns the image (e.g. `maths/simple-node-docker`)
2. The `cmd` doesn't seem to include a command for copying anything. I'm not familiar with node, but it looks like this starts `npm` and then does nothing else. Perhaps npm loads and runs your script by default? If so, it might help to post your script as well.